# To be in (good / bad) shape

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

As you are well aware, when someone has a nice physique, we can say:

> - He/she is in good shape.

But in case someone is "out of shape", I know that native speakers normally would say:

> - He/she is **out of** shape.

The question is that whether we can refer to such a person as follows:

> - He/she is in **bad** shape. 
>   can we say:

Does it sound idiomatic to you? If no, please kindly explain that to me.

Comment: to be in bad shape is not usually physical but it can be. For physical shape, we tend to use: out of shape.

Comment: Here is [a site](https://www.espressoenglish.net/learn-english-phrases-out-of-shape-in-goodbad-shape) that explains this pretty well.

Comment: What @Lambie said. Though (because I'm a Brit?) I prefer *I'm out of condition* over *I'm out of shape*. But these usages don't really have anything to do with "looking good" (to other people), except insofar as being *healthy/fit* also correlates with being attractive. Hence in the modern vernacular, *She's fit!* means she's *attractive* (not necessarily *healthy*, though she may be that as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say someone is in "bad shape" or "out of shape" are almost equally used when referring to someone else's physical fitness.

However, one thing to note is that "bad shape" can mean something else.

"I'm in bad shape" can also mean I am injured.  Or unwell, as with a virus or hangover.  Or mentally or emotionally unwell.  This can also be used to refer to the state of others.

You will avoid confusion if you always use "out of shape" for physical fitness. And avoid rudeness if you never refer to someone else with that term.  Saying someone else is in "bad shape" is not always rude, if you are expressing a concern for their welfare, but would be a very familiar usage.