# How to negate "in good shape"

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms, expressions, sentence-choice

Please have a look on the following structures:

> 1. I’m in good shape.*[physically/emotionally/mentally/financially/generally etc.]* 
>    2. They are in a good economic shape.

How would you usually ***negate*** each case?

I think in the first case, it would be better to avoid using the collocation "bad shape" while
one thing to note is that "bad shape" can mean something else.
"I'm in bad shape" can also mean I am injured. Or unwell, as with a virus or hangover. Or mentally or emotionally unwell. [Source](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/265254/to-be-in-good-bad-shape)

This is why I think in first ceae to prevent from confusion it **would be better** to say:

> 1- I'm out of shape.

rather than "I'm in bad shape" just to be on the safe side.

But in order to the second case, I guess we can use either structures. I mean:

> 2.a. They are in bad economic shape. 
> 2.b. They are economically out of shape.

Please correct me if I am wrong and let me know if I am missing a point.

Thank you in advance everybody.

Comment: What about "I'm not in good shape."? By the way "good shape" is idiomatic. "A good shape"  is not.

Comment: You were right @Jack O'Flaherty. That was a typo. Thank you for pointing that out. I corrected my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negative of "They are in a good economic shape" would be either:

> They are **not** in good economic shape.

or

> They are in **poor** economic shape.

The same structure applies to all of your examples.

"Poor shape" could also be "bad shape", or "terrible shape" - it depends how bad you want to say it is! "Not in good shape" is probably the lesser of all, as you're not saying it is bad, just not good.

Make sure you have the correct understanding of *economic* vs *financial*.

Comment: Just how about "out of shape" @Astralbee? Is it reserved for physical conditions?